How to make subtasks trackable in Odoo
in odoo the project.task class has tasks and sub tasks , both are the same the only diffrence is the parent_id if it's empty then it is a task , and if it has a parent_id then it's a subtask.
i found that tasks are trackable but subtasks are not, how to make the subtasks trackable too

in the settings go to project then you can find sub-tasks checkbox to unable history for subtasks, then in the formview of any task you'll find a smart button to lead you to the a list view of the task's subtasks , after that just select any subtask and you will se its history.

You can edit the project.action_view_all_task action and override the domain.
Currently it is: [('display_in_project', '=', True)]
You can put: []
